# Add extra criteria to COUNTIF

Tags: excel

My COUNTIF formula currently looks like this:

```
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ4)
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ5)
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ6)
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ7)
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ8)
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z, Dashboard!AJ9)
...etc
```

How do I add an extra criteria so that it ONLY counts values in **worksheet Master Data Set column Z** if there is also a match in **worksheet Master Data Set column V** when compared with **worksheet Dashboard A6:A41** (so both names have to appear in both columns)?

Comment: have you thought of pivot & filtering?

Comment: @FranzEbner - need it in a formula

Comment: @pnuts No - it wouldn't be counted

Comment: @pnuts - nothing comes up

Comment: @pnuts what do you mean

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Have you tried using the countifs() function? it allows for multiple criteria. It is available in newer versions of Excel (I believe 2007 and newer).

Comment: i think `Countifs` really can do this :D unless you're using 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
=COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!Z:Z,Dashboard!AJ4)*(COUNTIF('Master Data Set'!V:V,Dashboard!$A6)>0)
```

Comment: @pnuts you are right. I edited the answer, but I'm still not quite sure what the OP wants.